# Smoothing pixels on Unity's Images component using a customized Default UI shader

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, hlsl, smoothing

I'm looking to create a fade in/fade out effect for UI images using a customized shader.

Right now I'm working with this code:

```
// Unity built-in shader source. Copyright (c) 2016 Unity Technologies. MIT 
license (see license.txt)

Shader "Custom/FadeShader"
{
    Properties
    {
    [PerRendererData] _MainTex("Sprite Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
    [PerRendererData] _Cutoff("Cutoff", Range(0, 1)) = 0
    _Color("Tint", Color) = (1,1,1,1)

    _TransitionTex("Transition Texture", 2D) = "white" {}

    _StencilComp("Stencil Comparison", Float) = 8
    _Stencil("Stencil ID", Float) = 0
    _StencilOp("Stencil Operation", Float) = 0
    _StencilWriteMask("Stencil Write Mask", Float) = 255
    _StencilReadMask("Stencil Read Mask", Float) = 255

    _ColorMask("Color Mask", Float) = 15

    [Toggle(UNITY_UI_ALPHACLIP)] _UseUIAlphaClip("Use Alpha Clip", Float) = 0
    }

    SubShader
    {
        Tags
        {
            "Queue" = "Transparent"
            "IgnoreProjector" = "True"
            "RenderType" = "Transparent"
            "PreviewType" = "Plane"
            "CanUseSpriteAtlas" = "True"
        }

        Stencil
        {
            Ref[_Stencil]
            Comp[_StencilComp]
            Pass[_StencilOp]
            ReadMask[_StencilReadMask]
            WriteMask[_StencilWriteMask]
        }

        Cull Off
        Lighting Off
        ZWrite Off
        ZTest[unity_GUIZTestMode]
        Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
        ColorMask[_ColorMask]

        Pass
        {
            Name "Default"
        CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #pragma target 2.0

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"
            #include "UnityUI.cginc"

            #pragma multi_compile_local _ UNITY_UI_CLIP_RECT
            #pragma multi_compile_local _ UNITY_UI_ALPHACLIP

            struct appdata_t
            {
                float4 vertex   : POSITION;
                float4 color    : COLOR;
                float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
                UNITY_VERTEX_INPUT_INSTANCE_ID
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float4 vertex   : SV_POSITION;
                fixed4 color : COLOR;
                float2 texcoord  : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 worldPosition : TEXCOORD1;
                UNITY_VERTEX_OUTPUT_STEREO
            };

            sampler2D _MainTex;
            fixed4 _Color;
            fixed4 _TextureSampleAdd;
            float4 _ClipRect;
            float4 _MainTex_ST;

            sampler2D _TransitionTex;
            float _Cutoff;

            v2f vert(appdata_t v)
            {
                v2f OUT;
                UNITY_SETUP_INSTANCE_ID(v);
                UNITY_INITIALIZE_VERTEX_OUTPUT_STEREO(OUT);
                OUT.worldPosition = v.vertex;
                OUT.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(OUT.worldPosition);

                OUT.texcoord = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.texcoord, _MainTex);

                OUT.color = v.color * _Color;
                return OUT;
            }

            fixed4 frag(v2f IN) : SV_Target
            {
                fixed4 transit = tex2D(_TransitionTex, IN.texcoord);

                half4 color = (tex2D(_MainTex, IN.texcoord) + _TextureSampleAdd) * IN.color;

                #ifdef UNITY_UI_CLIP_RECT
                color.a *= UnityGet2DClipping(IN.worldPosition.xy, _ClipRect);
                #endif

                #ifdef UNITY_UI_ALPHACLIP
                clip(color.a - 0.001);
                #endif

                if (transit.b < _Cutoff)
                    color = lerp(0, color, saturate(_Cutoff - transit));

                clip(color.a - _Cutoff+0.1f);

                return color;
            }
        ENDCG
        }
    }
```

}

Which is essentially Unity's default UI shader with added cutoff value and a transition texture which decide how much the Image is faded in or out.

The current version of the shader produces this effect:
[image: Result image after using the shader]
Which is very pixelated on the edges in comparison to the source transition texture:
[image: Source transition texture]

I would like the edges to be smoothed out as I'm trying to achieve a hand drawn/comic style.

This [thread](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1121005/smoothing-pixels-via-shader-tree-leaf-shader.html) proposes using modifying the shader to work like the SoftOcclusion shader from Unity, I haven't had much luck with making it work however.

**EDIT**

For reference, I'm looking to create an effect like the one in Hades seen in [this video](https://youtu.be/sZ19bQyrOes?t=972) (timestamped).

[image: Hades reference 1]
[image: Hades reference 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to solve the issue by introducing another value (_CutoffRange) to the shader and changing the alpha of the color depending on the _CutoffRange value.

The full code for the working shader:

```
Shader "Custom/FadeShader"
{
    Properties
    {
        [PerRendererData] _MainTex("Sprite Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Color("Tint", Color) = (1,1,1,1)

        _TransitionTex("Transition Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Cutoff("Cutoff", Range(0, 1)) = 0
        _CutoffRange("Cutoff Range", Range(0,1)) = 0.1

        _StencilComp("Stencil Comparison", Float) = 8
        _Stencil("Stencil ID", Float) = 0
        _StencilOp("Stencil Operation", Float) = 0
        _StencilWriteMask("Stencil Write Mask", Float) = 255
        _StencilReadMask("Stencil Read Mask", Float) = 255

        _ColorMask("Color Mask", Float) = 15

        [Toggle(UNITY_UI_ALPHACLIP)] _UseUIAlphaClip("Use Alpha Clip", Float) = 0
    }

    SubShader
    {
        Tags
        {
            "Queue" = "Transparent"
            "IgnoreProjector" = "True"
            "RenderType" = "Transparent"
            "PreviewType" = "Plane"
            "CanUseSpriteAtlas" = "True"
        }

        Stencil
        {
            Ref[_Stencil]
            Comp[_StencilComp]
            Pass[_StencilOp]
            ReadMask[_StencilReadMask]
            WriteMask[_StencilWriteMask]
        }

        Cull Off
        Lighting Off
        ZWrite Off
        ZTest[unity_GUIZTestMode]
        Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
        ColorMask[_ColorMask]

        Pass
        {
            Name "Default"
        CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #pragma target 2.0

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"
            #include "UnityUI.cginc"

            #pragma multi_compile_local _ UNITY_UI_CLIP_RECT
            #pragma multi_compile_local _ UNITY_UI_ALPHACLIP

            struct appdata_t
            {
                float4 vertex   : POSITION;
                float4 color    : COLOR;
                float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
                UNITY_VERTEX_INPUT_INSTANCE_ID
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float4 vertex   : SV_POSITION;
                fixed4 color : COLOR;
                float2 texcoord  : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 worldPosition : TEXCOORD1;
                UNITY_VERTEX_OUTPUT_STEREO
            };

            sampler2D _MainTex;
            fixed4 _Color;
            fixed4 _TextureSampleAdd;
            float4 _ClipRect;
            float4 _MainTex_ST;

            sampler2D _TransitionTex;
            half _Cutoff;
            half _CutoffRange;

            v2f vert(appdata_t v)
            {
                v2f OUT;
                UNITY_SETUP_INSTANCE_ID(v);
                UNITY_INITIALIZE_VERTEX_OUTPUT_STEREO(OUT);
                OUT.worldPosition = v.vertex;
                OUT.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(OUT.worldPosition);

                OUT.texcoord = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.texcoord, _MainTex);

                OUT.color = v.color * _Color;
                return OUT;
            }

            fixed4 frag(v2f IN) : SV_Target
            {
                half4 transit = tex2D(_TransitionTex, IN.texcoord);
                half4 color = (tex2D(_MainTex, IN.texcoord) + _TextureSampleAdd) * IN.color;

                #ifdef UNITY_UI_CLIP_RECT
                color.a *= UnityGet2DClipping(IN.worldPosition.xy, _ClipRect);
                #endif

                #ifdef UNITY_UI_ALPHACLIP
                clip(color.a - 0.001);
                #endif

                half r = _Cutoff * (1 + _CutoffRange * 2) - _CutoffRange;
                color.a *= saturate((transit.b - _Cutoff) / _CutoffRange);

                return color;
            }
        ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```